# Error installing simple_draw: 404 on bitbucket URL

Tags: python, pip

I tried my best but couldn't find the solution.

I'm using Python 3.9

I tried to install a library with `pip install simple_draw` but cmd keeps showing this error.

I tried adding '--user', adding '--pre'. Didn't help. I also tried installing some earlier versions of pip but the error was the same. I attached the full text of the error below. *Please help I'm so lost...*

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]

C:\Users\gudmo_000>pip install simple_draw
Collecting simple_draw
  Using cached simple_draw-2.6.8.tar.gz (7.2 kB)
Collecting pygame==2.0.0.dev8
  Using cached pygame-2.0.0.dev8.tar.gz (5.5 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\gudmo_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.
exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\gudmo_0
00\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ybn9qp8\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__=
'"'"'C:\\Users\\gudmo_000\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ybn9qp8\\pygame\\s
etup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().r
eplace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"
'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\gudmo_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip
-egg-info-6jzfdnhw'
         cwd: C:\Users\gudmo_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ybn9qp8\pygame\

    Complete output (54 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\gudmo_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ybn9qp8\pygame\se
tup.py", line 295, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\gudmo_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ybn9qp8\pygame\bu
ildconfig\config.py", line 221, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\gudmo_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ybn9qp8\pygame\bu
ildconfig\config_win.py", line 559, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\gudmo_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ybn9qp8\pygame\bu
ildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 275, in ask
        update(x86=x86, x64=x64, sdl2=sdl2)
      File "C:\Users\gudmo_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ybn9qp8\pygame\bu
ildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 258, in update
        download_prebuilts(download_dir, x86=x86, x64=x64, sdl2=sdl2)
      File "C:\Users\gudmo_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ybn9qp8\pygame\bu
ildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 107, in download_prebuilts
        download_sha1_unzip(url, checksum, temp_dir, 1)
      File "C:\Users\gudmo_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ybn9qp8\pygame\bu
ildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 40, in download_sha1_unzip
        response = urllib.urlopen(request).read()
      File "c:\users\gudmo_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\urllib
\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "c:\users\gudmo_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\urllib
\request.py", line 523, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "c:\users\gudmo_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\urllib
\request.py", line 632, in http_response
        response = self.parent.error(
      File "c:\users\gudmo_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\urllib
\request.py", line 561, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "c:\users\gudmo_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\urllib
\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "c:\users\gudmo_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\urllib
\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
    Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
    Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.12-VC.zip 6839b
6ec345ef754a6585ab24f04e125e88c3392
    Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.12-VC.zip:
    Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-
devel-2.0.5-VC.zip 137f86474691f4e12e76e07d58d5920c8d844d5b
    Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip:
    Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-deve
l-2.0.15-VC.zip 1436df41ebc47ac36e02ec9bda5699e80ff9bd27
    Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip:
    Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-
devel-2.0.4-VC.zip 9097148f4529cf19f805ccd007618dec280f0ecc
    Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip:
    Downloading... https://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsr9d.zip ed10aa2b5a0fcfe74f8a6f
7611aeb346b06a1f99
    Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\jpegsr9d.zip:
    Downloading... https://bitbucket.org/llindstrom/pygame/downloads/prebuilt-x6
4-pygame-1.9.2-20150922.zip 3a5af3427b3aa13a0aaf5c4cb08daaed341613ed

    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check th
e logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The actual error is that the URL https://bitbucket.org/llindstrom/pygame/downloads/prebuilt-x64-pygame-1.9.2-20150922.zip is not valid (any longer?)

Comment: also it is simple-draw, here is [link](https://pypi.org/project/simple-draw/)

Comment: thank you for answering!

to Matiiss: tried changing its name to 'simple-draw', still the same error. \

to tripleee: but what do I do instead? how can I use another link?